# How to set what set which graphics card an application will use on Windows 10 desktop

Tags: windows, windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a Windows 10 desktop computer with three Nvidia graphics cards.  All Quadros.  Applications/games default to using the slower Nvidia card (it happens to show up first in the list in the Nvidia Control panel and needs to be set as Windows primary card/monitor).

Is there any way (Nvidia setting, Windows setting, utility program, etc) to control which graphics card an application uses?

This is a work provided PC and I can't swap the slots that cards are installed in and it doesn't have the April 2018 Windows 10 update yet.  It is not a laptop so does not have the Nvidia Optimus settings that many people mention in forums.

Thank you.

Comment: if it's a work PC then I'd engage with onsite support and ask them. If swapping the cards around will help, they may be able to do it, or allow you to do so.

Comment: I've got a Nvidia only single card machine, I've got the 'Program settings' option in the Nvidia control panel, where on a laptop, i'd be able to choose the GPU for specific programs. Do you not have that option also?

Comment: There are a number of PC's that are all configured this way.  And due to some specialized applications we are using it may not be possible to rearrange the cards.

Comment: Desktops do not have that option to run programs on a specific GPU setting in the Nvidia program settings.  That's part of Nvidia Optimus which is just for laptops.  If there is a way to enable it on desktops I'd love to know but I don't think there is

Comment: I need to whack another card in this machine and check out what I get. Nvidia support may be able to assist you.

Comment: I chatted with Nvidia support for a while.  They suggested using the nView control panel to set the application to launch on the display with the better graphics card (this did not help in my case).  Then suggested that the secondary display (with the better card) needs to be set as the primary display, but this causes other problems for us in our environment.  We need the first output to be Windows primary display